# How can I programmatically open a new tab in a webkit browser (chrome/safari)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari

How do you open a new tab in a webkit browser?
Here is my code:

```
if(data5 != false)
  window.open(data5, '_blank');
else
  alert("Cannot locate the file. Please contact administrator.");
```

It works well in Firefox. But for chrome and safari, it opens as a separate window.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You just cannot affect if a browser opens a new window or a new tab on `window.open()`. That is a user setting (most of the times) and is not allowed to be changed by script.

---

**update**:

webkit is a little strict on opening new windows/tabs due to script. When you try to execute a `window.open()` via console on some site, you most likely get this one:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL "Some URL" from
>   frame with URL http://www.stackoverflow.com. Domains, protocols and
>   ports must match.

Comment: thank a lot for yr comment. I already opened javascript option to allow pop up window for this site.But I can't. Why do u know?

Comment: @sandy: see updated answer. I'd recommend to have a look in the console output of webkits 'developer tools'.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open a new tab programmatically through Javascript.

New Tab option is a user-defined property in browsers. It opens in Firefox because in preferences it must be set that new window is to be opened in a new tab.

Comment: Thank for your answer. But can you kindly advice me? how can I do to open new tab programmatically?

Comment: He's saying there is no physical way whatsoever

Answer (score 0):

It´s up to the user to decide how and where the new window should open by configurating their browser settings.

Comment: thank a lot for yr comment. I already opened javascript option to allow pop up window for this site.But I can't. Why do u know?