# How can i simulate Ctrl+link?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, google-chrome

I tried to use SnedKeys:

```
SendKeys.SendWait("^" + "http://stackoverflow.com/");
```

What i want to do is to simulate the combination of Ctrl+link so it will open a new browser tab in the background.
From the chrome document: "Press Ctrl and click a link  Open the link in a new tab in the background"

I also tried before first:

```
SendKeys.Send("^" + "http://stackoverflow.com/");
```

But then getting exception:

> InvalidOperationException
>
> SendKeys cannot run inside this application because the application is not handling Windows messages.  Either change the application to handle messages, or use the SendKeys.SendWait method.

Comment: Well, the `InvalidOperationException` is self-explanatory.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/8294139

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ctrl+link only works if you are clicking on the mouse.  Since you want to send keys, you need to use the appropriate keystrokes (Ctrl+N, then the url, then enter), so I would do this:

```
SendKeys.SendWait("^n");
SendKeys.SendWait("http://www.stackoverflow.com~");
```

The full code to test this (activating the window properly):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

// For Windows Mobile, replace user32.dll with coredll.dll
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr GetWindow(IntPtr hWnd, GetWindow_Cmd uCmd);

enum GetWindow_Cmd : uint
{
    GW_HWNDFIRST = 0,
    GW_HWNDLAST = 1,
    GW_HWNDNEXT = 2,
    GW_HWNDPREV = 3,
    GW_OWNER = 4,
    GW_CHILD = 5,
    GW_ENABLEDPOPUP = 6
}

private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    IntPtr chromeWindow = FindWindow("Chrome_WidgetWin_1", null);
    IntPtr chrome = GetWindow(chromeWindow, GetWindow_Cmd.GW_HWNDNEXT);

    SetForegroundWindow(chrome);

    SendKeys.SendWait("^n");
    SendKeys.SendWait("http://www.stackoverflow.com~");
}
```

Note, I used the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21776450/setting-active-a-chrome-window-c) on finding and activating the chrome window.

Comment: John this is working with the SendKeys but is there any way to hide the window or to make that it will open it in the background so the user will not see that the program open the new chrome window ? I mean that the focus will stay on the current window i'm in and won't move to focus on the new chrome window.

Comment: You could call this.Acitvate() to re-activate your form.  If you want it completely in the background, then you would have to use some windows messaging to send the text instead of using sendkeys.